# Who gave you infinitesimal epsilon?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, reference-request

As someone reputed among certain historians to have *given you the epsilon* Cauchy startled me by using $\varepsilon$ to denote an infinitely small *number* in his 1826 text on differential geometry; see page 98 [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=PPN591098687):

> [S]i l'on désigne par $\varepsilon$ un nombre infiniment petit, on aura $$ \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\varepsilon\right)}{r}= \frac{\sin(\pm\Delta\tau)}{\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}} $$

Are there other instances of such nonweierstrassian usage by Cauchy?

Comment: Maybe [Resumé](https://books.google.it/books?id=uN5UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA13) (1823), *4ème Lecon*, page 13: "Soient ... $i$ une quantité infiniment petite, et $h$ une quantité finie. Si l'on pose $i=\alpha x$, $\alpha$ sera encore une quantité infiniment petite, et l'on aura...$\dfrac {f(x+ \alpha h)-f(x)} { \alpha}$" where $i$ and $\alpha$ are used for "infinitesimal small" quantities.

Comment: Also on page [27](https://books.google.it/books?id=uN5UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA27) and [83](https://books.google.it/books?id=uN5UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA83) of this volume $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ appear as "nombres tres-petits" and as quantities differing "tres peu de zero".